# Check if file is signed

Tags: java, certificate

I saw that some websites when you upload the file know that I "signed" the file with a certain certificate. How can I go about checking the signature and who signed the file using something like java?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Who signed the file, what kind of file is it, was the signature attached to the file, what encryption framework was used to do the signing / verification.